# PJPROJECT building error?

Tags: asterisk

i am trying to install PJPROJECT using following commands:

[Note]: the server where i am installing it does not have internet accessibility so i have to manually install every thing...

1) untar pjproject file

2) ./configure CFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -DPJ_HAS_IPV^=1" --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-shared --disable-opencore-amr

3) make dep

4) make

Here i am facing following error:

```
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc: In function ‘void libyuv::YuvPixel(uint8, uint8, uint8, uint8*, uint8*, uint8*, const libyuv::YuvConstants*)’:
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1256: error: invalid types ‘const signed char vector[int]’ for array subscript
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1257: error: invalid types ‘const signed char vector[int]’ for array subscript
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1258: error: invalid types ‘const signed char vector[int]’ for array subscript
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1259: error: invalid types ‘const signed char vector[int]’ for array subscript
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1260: error: invalid types ‘const short int vector[int]’ for array subscript
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1261: error: invalid types ‘const short int vector[int]’ for array subscript
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1262: error: invalid types ‘const short int vector[int]’ for array subscript
../../yuv/source/row_common.cc:1263: error: invalid types ‘const short int vector[int]’ for array subscript
make[3]: *** [output/libyuv-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/row_common.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/Asterisk/Asterisk_13.8/Asterisk/missing_packages/pjproject-2.6/third_party/build/yuv'
make[2]: *** [libyuv-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/Asterisk/Asterisk_13.8/Asterisk/missing_packages/pjproject-2.6/third_party/build/yuv'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/Asterisk/Asterisk_13.8/Asterisk/missing_packages/pjproject-2.6/third_party/build'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

what causes this error to occur and how to resolve this issue??
i also tries to change ./configure parameters like on running
`./configure --enable-shared` only i get:

```
**output/libgsmcodec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/add.o: could not read symbols: Bad value**
**collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**
**make[3]: *** [../../lib/libgsmcodec.so.2] Error 1**
**make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/Asterisk/Asterisk_13.8/Asterisk/missing_packages/pjproject-2.6/third_party/build/gsm'**
**make[2]: *** [libgsmcodec.so] Error 2**
**make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/Asterisk/Asterisk_13.8/Asterisk/missing_packages/pjproject-2.6/third_party/build/gsm'**
**make[1]: *** [all] Error 1**
**make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/Asterisk/Asterisk_13.8/Asterisk/missing_packages/pjproject-2.6/third_party/build'**
**make: *** [all] Error 1**
```